# JW Player Autoplaying the Audio/Video

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have used JWPlayer in one of my application.
And when I use to drag the Progress Bar/Or click anywhere on the Progress bar of a PAUSED audio/video.
It AUTOMATICALLY PLAYS the file.
I don't want it to happen, Is there any solution for that?

I have already tried setting autostart feature to False but nothing positive.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: That's normal behavior for JW Player, and I don't think there's any way to change it. If you're playing a video, then pause it, then drag the seek marker, the video starts playing from the new seek point. It doesn't stay in "paused" mode. It's interesting, however, that the HTML5 <video> tag does NOT behave that way - it stays paused in all browsers.